# I have a UIImageView in a UITableView Header. How can I get the exact y/x coordinates of that UIImageView at any time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a UIImageView in a UITableView Header. How can I get the exact y/x coordinates of that UIImageView at any time?

I need to know the exact x/y points on the screen, even as a user scrolls up and down within the tableview. If this is possible, can someone point me to some sample code?

Just calling this does not work:

```
itemImageView.frame.origin.x, itemImageView.frame.origin.y
```

It just gives me the coordinates as they relate to the tableView itself, regardless of it's actual position on the window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want is the UIView convertPoint view.  You can convert the point you get to the table view's space.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView:

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `CGRect rect = [infoTableView convertRect:itemImageView.frame toView:nil];` and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!